# Django return JSON with Logged in Cookie

Tags: python, json, django, cookies

I want to design a simple Django "RESTful" API without the need of using django-rest-framework.

The endpoint is `/api/login` which accept only POST method with `username` and `password` in json. I want it to return `{"status" : 0}` for success with the session cookie to be used later at my other endpoints. Only when the user successfully logged in, the cookie will be set.

I have imported the `JsonResponse` object from `django.http` but not very sure how to set the session for the user.

```
def login(request):
    # some code omitted, like if request.method == "POST"
    credential = json.loads(request.body)
    username = credential['username']
    password = credential['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"status" : 1, "err" : "Your account has been disabled"})
        # TODO: Now return what?
```

I have browsed the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) but failed to find any useful tip.

Comment: Suggestion unrelated to question: To prevent KeyError, you should do `username = credential.get('username')` and then check if username is `None` before proceeding. Also, do the same for password.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out, that I can just use `return JsonResponse({'status' : 0})` because the cookies are registered with Django because of `authenticate`.